# How to check collision of 2 Rectangles between classes?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm trying to check collision of a Rectangle between 2 classes; Game1.cs and Terrain.cs.

Somehow when I change my Terrain.cs constructor to include the Rectangle to detect collision with, it takes the Rectangle, but can't change it in the Update method. For example, I made a Rectangle called playerRectangle, and asked for a playerRectangle in the `Terrain` constructor, and I added code inside the `Terrain` constructor:

```
this.playerRectangle = playerRectangle;
```

In the Game1 update method I made a for loop that updated an array of `Terrain` objects. I tested to see if it would change the position of the playerRectangle by adding code in the Terrain.cs update method:

```
playerRectangle.X = 200;
```

The original playerRectangle X is 450. It stayed at 450. No changes whatsoever.

Can anyone find out the problem here?

Terrain constructor:

```
public Terrain(ContentManager contentManager, Rectangle playerRectangle, Texture2D chunkSprite, int y, int x)
    {
        chunks = chunkSprite;
        this.y = y;
        this.x = y;
        this.playerRectangle = playerRectangle;

        //Load drawRectangle
        drawRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);

    }
```

for loop to load:

```
for (int i = 0; i < terrain.Length; i++)
        {
            number2 += 50;
            terrain[i] = new Terrain(Content, drawRectangle, sprite, 550, number2);
        }
```

update:

```
for (int i = 0; i < terrain.Length; i++)
        {
            terrain[i].Update(gameTime);
        }
```

and draw:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < terrain.Length; i++)
        {
            terrain[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
playerRectangle.X = 200;
```

do this:

```
playerRectangle = new Rectangle (200, playerRectangle.Y, playerRectangle.Width, playerRectangle.Height);
```

Changing a property of the playerRectangle probably doesn't trigger the right notification

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, stays the same throughout, not sure why. Should I create an entirely new class that makes the Player instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you try to update it, but there should be something wrong.
Maybe what you need is a method in your `Terrain` class to change `playerRectangle`, something like:

```
public void SetPlayerRectangle(Rectangle rect)
{
   this.playerRectangle = rect;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this method?

Comment: Inside the Terrain.cs method.

Comment: If you can add the method where you call this piece of code it would be useful.